# How to update block attribute after format is applied?

Tags: block-editor

StackExchange community,

I have created a custom format using the rich-text package according to the Format API. We have a need to update the block attribute with the value of the custom format. To summarize we are looking for the following to happen:

1. Insert paragraph block
2. Highlight word
3. Click custom format button (opens popover)
4. Select option from select input
5. Format applies to word
6. Selected option is updated to paragraph block attribute

Currently we have it setup to where the option selected will be added to an array of values if there are multiple custom formats applied on the same paragraph block. I will try to condense the code I am working with below.

```
/* index.js */
import { createElement, useState } from '@wordpress/element';
import { useSelect, useDispatch } from '@wordpress/data';
import { URLPopover, RichTextToolbarButton } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { registerFormatType, getActiveFormat, useAnchorRef } from '@wordpress/rich-text';
import { default as CustomFormatPopover } from './components/custom-popover';

const {
    name,
    activeAttributes,
    activeObjectAttributes,
    value,
    onChange,
    contentRef,
} = props

const formatName = 'dnk-blocks/custom-format';
const [ isOpen, setOpen ] = useState( false );
const openPopover = () => setOpen( true );
const closePopover = () => setOpen( false );
const clientId = useSelect( select => select( 'core/block-editor' ).getSelectedBlockClientId() );

const getInlineModals = () => {
    const formats = value.formats
    
    let formatValues = []
    
    // Check dispatched attributes 
    if ( formats ) {
        formats.forEach( ( format ) => {
            if ( format.type === formatName ) {
                if ( format.attributes && format.attributes.customFormats  ) {
                    formatValues.push( Number( format.attributes.customFormats ) )
                }
                if ( format.unregisteredAttributes && format.unregisteredAttributes.customformats ) {
                    formatValues.push( Number( format.unregisteredAttributes.customformats ) )
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    return formatValues
}

function changeAttribute() {
    return updateBlockAttributes( clientId, { 
        customFormats: getCustomFormats()
    } )
}

return (
    <>
        <RichTextToolbarButton
            icon={ formatIcon }
            title="Custom Format"
            onClick={ openPopover }
            isActive={ isActive() }
        />
        { isOpen && (
            <CustomFormatPopover
                name={ formatName }
                value={ value }
                onClose={ closePopover }
                onChange={ ( ...args ) => onChange( ...args ) }
                isFormat={ true }
                anchorRef={ anchorRef }
                changeAttribute={ changeAttribute }
            />
        ) }
    </>
);
```

```
/* /components/custom-popover */

import { useSelect, useDispatch } from '@wordpress/data';
import { URLPopover } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import {
    applyFormat,
    removeFormat,
    getActiveFormat,
    toggleFormat,
    getActiveObject,
} from '@wordpress/rich-text';

export default function CustomFormatPopover( props ) {
    
    const {
        name,
        value,
        onChange,
        onClose,
        anchorRef,
        attributes,
        setAttributes,
        inlineModals,
        activeAttributes,
        changeAttribute,
    } = props

    // Detect selected modal from active formats
    const getActiveFormats = () => {
        const customFormat = getActiveFormat( value, name );
        
        if ( ! customFormat ) {
            return '';
        }

        if ( customFormat.attributes.hasOwnProperty('customFormats') ) {
            return customFormat.attributes['customFormats'];
        }

        if ( customFormat.unregisteredAttributes.hasOwnProperty('customFormats') ) {
            return customFormat.unregisteredAttributes['customFormats'];
        }
    };
    
    function setFormat ( option ) {
        return applyFormat( value, {
            type: name,
            attributes: {
                name: 'dnk_custom_format',
                customFormats: option,
            },
        } )
    }

    const changeCustomFormat = option =>  onChange( setFormat( option ) );
    const removeCustomFormat = () => onChange( removeFormat( value, name ) );

    return (
            <Popover
                value={ value }
                onClose={ onClose }
                anchorRef={ anchorRef }
            >
                <PanelBody>
                    <SelectControl
                        label="Select a custom format"
                        value={ getActiveFormats() }
                        options={ options }
                        onChange={ changeCustomFormat }
                    />
                    
                    { getActiveModal() !== '' &&
                        <Button
                            onClick={ removeCustomFormat }
                            isLink
                            isDestructive
                        >
                            Remove
                        </Button>
                    }
                </PanelBody>
            </Popover>
    );
}
```

The problem that I have been wrestling with is how to (1st) apply the custom format and then (2nd) update the block attribute with the recently changed format. The attribute would be an updated array of all the custom format values used in the paragraph block. I apologize for the lengthy post, any help would be greatly appreciated.